# SQL select rows if subsequent match not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an example SQL query that returns result like this:

| CLIENT | REQUESTDATE | COUNTRY | ARRIVAL | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-04-01 | Australia | 2020-03-15 | Closed |
| B | 2020-02-12 | Germany | 2021-05-03 | Closed |
| C | 2019-10-21 | Italy | 2020-03-06 | Closed |
| D | 2019-09-11 | United Kingdom | 2020-03-01 | Closed |
| EEE | 2020-01-30 | Netherlands | 2020-03-23 | Sold |
| F | 2019-06-10 | South Africa | 2020-02-15 | Closed |
| G | 2019-08-26 | Luxembourg | 2020-08-25 | Closed |
| HHH | 2019-04-09 | India | 2021-03-21 | Sold |
| HHH | 2019-10-10 | India | 2020-10-12 | Closed |
| HHH | 2020-10-14 | India | 2021-09-12 | Follow up |

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT
Clients.name as CLIENT,
Requests.requestDate AS REQUESTDATE,
Countries.name as COUNTRY, 
Requests.arrivalDate AS ARRIVAL,
RequestStatus.name as STATUS 
FROM Clients 
JOIN Countries ON Countries.id=Clients.countryId 
JOIN RequestClientEvent ON RequestClientEvent.clientId=Clients.id 
JOIN Requests ON Requests.requestClientEventId=RequestClientEvent.id 
JOIN RequestStatus ON RequestStatus.id=Requests.requestStatusId 
AND Requests.arrivalDate >= '2020-01-01' 
GROUP BY Clients.name, RequestStatus.id
ORDER BY Clients.name, Requests.requestDate, RequestStatus.id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to return only Clients with Status "Sold", that are not followed by any subsequent records (by RequestDate) for the same Client.

So that the query for example returns Client "EEE" based on the table above.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aliases you need to join to the same Request table twice, one `closedR` contains the closed request, and the `subsequentR` contains anything of a greater date.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Clients C
JOIN Request closedR
  ON closedR.requestClientEventId=C.id
     AND closedR.status="Closed"
LEFT JOIN Request subsequentR
  ON subsequentR.requestClientEventId = C.id
     AND subsequentR.requestDate > closedR.requestDate
WHERE subsequentR.id IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` / `WHERE .. IS NULL` allows you to find anything that doesn't match.